# Fuse ESB - Camel issue

Tags: apache-camel, xslt-2.0, fuseesb, osgi-bundle

We are trying to install a bundle using osgi in Fuse ESB 7.1.0.
Inside this bundle, in camel-context we are using like below:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <endpoint uri="http://IPADDRESS:8080/LOB_Webservice/LOBSampleWebService?throwExceptionOnFailure=false" id="callLOBServer"/>
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:lobclient?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
        <to uri="log:output"/>
        <bean ref="enrichBean"/>
        <to uri="xslt:etc/8.xsl"/>
         <bean ref="enrichBean"/>
         <to ref="callLOBServer"/>
         <bean ref="enrichBean"/>
        ***<to uri="xslt:etc/3.xsl"/>***
         <bean ref="enrichBean"/>
        <to uri="xslt:etc/7.xsl"/> 
        <bean ref="enrichBean"/>
        <to uri="log:output"/> 
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

The above 3.xsl is using `XSLT 2.0`.

When we try to install this, it is getting failed with below information:

```
15:11:23,047 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-4 | XsltErrorListener                | 147 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.0.fuse-71-047 | A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.; Line#: 8; Column#: 77
15:11:23,047 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-4 | ContextLoaderListener            | 113 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=org.apache.camel.camel-example-cxf-proxy, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_07]
    at org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil.getBundle(FrameworkUtil.java:208)[karaf.jar:2.3.0.fuse-71-047]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.util.OsgiUtil.getBundleOrNull(OsgiUtil.java:114)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.getClassDetail(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:148)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.formatElement(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:135)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.doRender(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:105)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.doRender(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:52)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:89)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:193)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:365)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:772)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.error(PaxLoggerImpl.java:159)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.TrackingLogger.error(TrackingLogger.java:96)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.error(Slf4jLogger.java:911)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltErrorListener.fatalError(XsltErrorListener.java:44)[147:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.java:614)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.RelativeLocationPath(XPathParser.java:1639)[:]
```

Here is the content of `3.xsl` also.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="return">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         <ordertotal>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(orderDetails/(itemPrice * itemQty))"/>
         </ordertotal>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when we try to replace 3.xsl with equivalent XSLT 1.0 functionality, its working fine.
As part of requirements, we need to work with XSLT 2.0 only.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Latest stack trace..

```
16:06:46,210 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-2 | XsltErrorListener                | 147 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.0.fuse-71-047 | A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.; Line#: 8; Column#: 78
16:06:46,210 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-2 | ContextLoaderListener            | 113 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=org.apache.camel.camel-example-cxf-proxy, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:332)[:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1144)[:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:462)[:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:403)[:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)[:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)[:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)[:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)[:1.7.0_07]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerWiring.getClassByDelegation(ExtensionManager.java:873)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1520)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1466)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)[:1.7.0_07]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1814)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:929)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:99)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:156)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)[:1.7.0_07]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.util.OsgiUtil.loadClass(OsgiUtil.java:99)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.findClass(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:221)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.formatElement(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:134)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.doRender(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:105)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer.doRender(OsgiThrowableRenderer.java:52)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:89)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:193)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:365)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:772)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.error(PaxLoggerImpl.java:159)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.TrackingLogger.error(TrackingLogger.java:96)[3:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.error(Slf4jLogger.java:911)[4:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltErrorListener.fatalError(XsltErrorListener.java:44)[147:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.java:614)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.RelativeLocationPath(XPathParser.java:1639)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.LocationPath(XPathParser.java:1597)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.PathExpr(XPathParser.java:1317)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.UnionExpr(XPathParser.java:1236)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.UnaryExpr(XPathParser.java:1142)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.MultiplicativeExpr(XPathParser.java:1063)[:]
```

Input XML file

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:fetchOrderListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://impl.lob.wipro.com/">
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>50.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>2</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>37516016-D71B-4790-951F-55D00B0CC159</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>39.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>6095ABC7-0D0D-4B2E-92E5-80F24E9092B8</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>84EC371D-40CA-455E-A0FA-7EA733E9BFD3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>54712493-2172-4ADB-814B-BC7AA0BB72C3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>565.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>1</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>9A5030BE-F95F-4C62-B5A2-41FF85423218</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>4.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>90</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>65A8B3BE-D407-43D8-8754-EA1E26AA56E4</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>0BDCB222-0117-47A9-8813-DF03A1D19E5E</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>8E4220DC-884B-47BC-A565-E26B80BA5249</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
           <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>10.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>4</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>5A2DF895-BB0F-4039-80DB-F44CED31697B</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>20.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>8034FBF4-B573-4B19-BDF5-FAF6C4247A55</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>60161E3E-3C4A-4CE6-AAC3-E4D2BC240046</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
      </ns2:fetchOrderListResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the XSLT is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="ordertotal">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../orderDetails/(itemPrice*itemQty))" />
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output expected..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:fetchOrderListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://impl.lob.wipro.com/">
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>50.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>2</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>37516016-D71B-4790-951F-55D00B0CC159</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>39.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>6095ABC7-0D0D-4B2E-92E5-80F24E9092B8</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>84EC371D-40CA-455E-A0FA-7EA733E9BFD3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>217</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>54712493-2172-4ADB-814B-BC7AA0BB72C3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>565.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>1</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>9A5030BE-F95F-4C62-B5A2-41FF85423218</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>4.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>90</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>65A8B3BE-D407-43D8-8754-EA1E26AA56E4</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>0BDCB222-0117-47A9-8813-DF03A1D19E5E</orderId>
            <ordertotal>925</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>8E4220DC-884B-47BC-A565-E26B80BA5249</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0</ordertotal>
           <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>10.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>4</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>5A2DF895-BB0F-4039-80DB-F44CED31697B</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>20.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>8034FBF4-B573-4B19-BDF5-FAF6C4247A55</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>60161E3E-3C4A-4CE6-AAC3-E4D2BC240046</orderId>
            <ordertotal>100</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
      </ns2:fetchOrderListResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

From the logs..(getting printed repeatedly..)

```
16:06:45,883 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-2 | XsltErrorListener                | 147 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.0.fuse-71-047 | A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.; Line#: 8; Column#: 78
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.java:610)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.RelativeLocationPath(XPathParser.java:1639)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.LocationPath(XPathParser.java:1597)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.PathExpr(XPathParser.java:1317)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.UnionExpr(XPathParser.java:1236)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.UnaryExpr(XPathParser.java:1142)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.MultiplicativeExpr(XPathParser.java:1063)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.AdditiveExpr(XPathParser.java:1005)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.RelationalExpr(XPathParser.java:930)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.EqualityExpr(XPathParser.java:870)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.AndExpr(XPathParser.java:834)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.OrExpr(XPathParser.java:807)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.Expr(XPathParser.java:790)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.Argument(XPathParser.java:1469)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.FunctionCall(XPathParser.java:1537)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.PrimaryExpr(XPathParser.java:1446)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.FilterExpr(XPathParser.java:1345)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.PathExpr(XPathParser.java:1278)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.UnionExpr(XPathParser.java:1236)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.UnaryExpr(XPathParser.java:1142)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.MultiplicativeExpr(XPathParser.java:1063)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.AdditiveExpr(XPathParser.java:1005)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.RelationalExpr(XPathParser.java:930)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.EqualityExpr(XPathParser.java:870)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.AndExpr(XPathParser.java:834)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.OrExpr(XPathParser.java:807)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.Expr(XPathParser.java:790)[:]
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:129)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:157)[:]
```

Comment: I am not familiar with your environment but the Sun/Oracle JRE only supports XSLT 1.0. If you want to use XSLT 2.0 with Java you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9. I don't know whether your environment allows you to integrate Saxon 9 however.

Comment: Hi Martin Honnen, yes it does, i also added saxon9 jar in my "Path" variable..

Comment: In a stand along fuse IDE, i can able to run a sample project which uses XSLT 2.0 with camel-saxon implementation. But when it comes to fuse esb, im **not** able to install the bundle successfully.

Comment: And did you install camel-saxon in the Fuse ESB before you installed your application bundle? And have you tried to restart the ESB afterwards just in case. Camel will log at INFO level if its using Saxon or the built-in from the JVM when its using the xpath/xslt the first time (I think we did add the logging for xlst also, though for xpath for sure we log)

Comment: And you get a stack overflow exception, wonder if the template somehow goes into a endless loop. Maybe try with a simpler template, and then add pieces to the template until it breaks.

Comment: Hi Claus, Many Thanks for your response.
I use fuse esb 7.1.0 version and in that i can able to see the jar(camel-saxon-2.10.0.fuse-71-047.jar)
inside the location (system\org\apache\camel\camel-saxon\2.10.0.fuse-71-047)
Also I understand that in 3.xsl(code given above) the only line(line#8) which is having xslt 2.0 function which is creating the problem.
I thought this is one of the simpler template(because the rest of the xsl you see in this are in 1.0 version).

Comment: Hi Claus, This is the steps i did. Installed Fuse ESB 7.1.0 and camel-saxon Deployed the application bundle. Added xalan.jar in "Path" system variable. The application is getting installed successfully if i use xslt version 1.0 code in camel-context. But whenever i tried to use xslt 2.0 related function like sum in this case its failing.. Could you please let me know if i miss something here..? Thanks. (PS: I update latest stack trace above. Thanks.)

Comment: Do you have a sample XML file which we can use as a test-case with your xslt 2.0 style template to try to reproduce this issue, and use that to work on a fix/workaround? That is much easier for engineering to track down a problem.

Comment: And the stacktrace above, is that the only error you see in the logs?

Comment: I updated the original post with sample input xml/xslt and output that we are expecting..I also updated the logs..

Comment: Hi @Ibsen, we were able to fix this issue by installing service mix saxon 9.3.0.11_2 and updating the camelcontext to explicitly use <to uri="xslt:etc/3.xsl?transformerFactory=tFactory"/> and adding the bean <bean id="tFactory" class="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah maybe we can add an option on xslt component to force it to use saxon, eg ?saxon=true.

Comment: Logged a ticket for that - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6183

Can you mark this question as answered then. eg Saxon is a much better to use than what the JDK has out of the box, which is often buggy and outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if with **Karaf + Apache camel** you are getting error for XSLT 2.0 such as one mentioned below, simply force **camel xslt component** to use saxon (camel-saxon) instead of default from the JDK.

This could also occur if you create ***new nodes*** in **karaf 4.x+** and with root node same xslt component could work but new nodes will try to pick xslt processor from JDK.

**Problem (Error Sample):**

```
 javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(current-dateTime, [])'.
```

**Solution (Example):**

```
<to uri="xslt:transformers/XSLT-Mappers/CustomerService-Response.xsl?saxon=true" />
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I am new to FUSE and all the stuff behind remains for me rather undiscovered yet. I have a question, though. Is there a way to configure default xslt processor without explicitly typing`?saxon=true`. The point is - we have a project in our company which has been deployed and I got assigned to provide minor changes. Therefore, I've been trying to run it locally without touching the implementation.